# How to Switch Partner portal User to Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning, community

I have a community with 100 Partners Users and I need to switch one or all of them to try lightning in that community but I don't know why I can't.

Answer (score 3):

Lightning Experience (and Classic) are specific to Internal Users. You don't turn it on/off for Community Users.

Community Users get access to your Org only through Communities. And that Communities can be built based on [different templates](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=siteforce_commtemp_intro.htm&type=5) which drives the UI/UX for that Community. So as long as your Community is built providing a Lightning User Experience, they will get the look and feel based on that. If your Community say is built on Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce and they primarily reflect the old look and feel, then you will need to redesign your Community.

Comment: you r right.. i have a Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce community. it is possible to contact my executive account and swap 100 partner community licenses to 100 sales licenses? I just need to use the lightning look n feel with tabs without developing an entire community.

the cost its more expensive?

Comment: While it's possible to switch Partner Users as your Internal Users, it will depend on your business use case scenario and organizational decision. I don't think onboarding them as Internal Users will be the right approach, because otherwise they wouldn't have been onboarded as Partner Users at first place. Additionally that will need lot of consideration starting from security to data sharing. You should evaluate license (depending on if you can have them as internal users) vs. creating lightning community and then make your decision.

Comment: They didnt started to use the tool so theres no problem with the data, i have no problem to configure de security but i dont know anaything about licenses cost and as you see, community builder. Convert a partner user to internal user its expensive right?

Comment: I would definitely think the license cost has differences. Your best bet on that will be your account executive.

Comment: I entered to the app with an internat user, change to lightning, and its exacty what i need, but im afraid of what it cost the swap

Comment: thanks for the help